# Deleting nodes gives problems to nodes that have been assigned the values, why? Why can't I alter node values in print function?

Tags: c, visual-studio

3 main problems:

1. Visual Studio won't print symbols such as a blank square, a heart, a Club, a spade etc.
2. When deleting a node from my linked list, I give its value to another node in another list, but when I delete it, it deletes the values of the node in the other list too, but idk why.
3. When printing my values I am trying to alter a value before printing, but it doesn't alter all of them.  It only works for the header.

I tried making my print function receive a double star'd node defined function but it didn't like that, I could've done it wrong though.  I have tried copy and pasting different spade and heart symbols but it always prints a question mark.  This is for Visual Studio 2015 btw.  Also my computerhand function isn't done yet, that'll just be to print the first three cards of the computer's hand.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rand_gen(int count) {
double frac;
frac = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
return floor(count * frac);
}
typedef struct card_s {
char suit;
int suitnum;
int face;
struct card_s *next, *previous;
}card;

void deletecard(card *p, card **hl) {
if (p == *hl) {
    *hl = p->next;
}
else {
    p->previous->next = p->next;
}
if (p->next == NULL) {
    p->previous->next = NULL;
}
else {
    p->next->previous = p->previous;
}
free(p);
}
void createdeck(card **hl) {
int i = 1;
int j;
int y = 0;
card* temp;
temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
card* temp2;
temp2 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
while (i <= 13) {
    j = 1;
    while (j <= 4) {
        temp2->face = i;
        temp2->suitnum = j;
        if (*hl == NULL) {
            temp->next = NULL;
            temp->previous = NULL;
            temp->face = 1;
            temp->suitnum = 1;
            (*hl) = temp;
        }
        else {
            temp->next = temp2;
            temp2->previous = temp;
            temp2->next = NULL;
            temp = temp->next;
            temp2 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
}
void printdeck(card *currentNode) {
printf("\n\n\n");
if (currentNode->suitnum == 1) {
    currentNode->suit = '♣';
}
else if (currentNode->suitnum == 2) {
    currentNode->suit = '♦';
}
else if (currentNode->suitnum == 3) {
    currentNode->suit = '♥';
}
else {
    currentNode->suit = '♠';
}
while (currentNode != NULL) {
    printf("Face: %d, Suit: %c\n", currentNode->face, currentNode->suit);
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
}
}

void shuffle(card *current) {
int x = 1;
while (x < 1000) {
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int y = 0;
    card* temp;
    card *temp2;
    card* temp3;
    temp3 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
    temp2 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
    temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
    while (i < 52) {
        int c = 0;
        int j = rand_gen(51);
        temp = current;
        while (c < j) {
            temp = temp->next;
            c++;
        }
        int y = 0;
        temp2 = current;
        while (y < i) {
            temp2 = temp2->next;
            y++;
        }
        temp3->face = temp2->face;
        temp3->suitnum = temp2->suitnum;
        temp2->face = temp->face;
        temp2->suitnum = temp->suitnum;
        temp->face = temp3->face;
        temp->suitnum = temp3->suitnum;
        i++;
    }
    x++;
}
}

void drawhand(card **player, card **computer, card **headl) {
int i = 0;
card* temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp = *headl;
*player = temp;
card* temp2 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp2 = temp->next;
deletecard(temp, headl);
*computer = temp2;
card* temp3 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp3 = temp2->next;
deletecard(temp2, headl);
(*player)->next = temp3;
card* temp4 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp4 = temp3->next;
deletecard(temp3, headl);
(*computer)->next = temp4;
card* temp5 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp5 = temp4->next;
deletecard(temp4, headl);
(*player)->next->next = temp5;
card* temp6 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp6 = temp5->next;
deletecard(temp5, headl);
(*computer)->next->next = temp6;
card* temp7 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp7 = temp6->next;
deletecard(temp6, headl);
(*player)->next->next->next = temp7;
card* temp8 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp8 = temp7->next;
deletecard(temp7, headl);
(*computer)->next->next->next = temp8;
card* temp9 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp9 = temp8->next;
deletecard(temp8, headl);
(*player)->next->next->next->next = temp9;
card* temp10 = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
temp10 = temp9->next;
deletecard(temp9, headl);
deletecard(temp10, headl);
(*player)->next->previous = *player;
(*player)->next->next->previous = (*player)->next;
(*player)->next->next->next->previous = (*player)->next->next;
(*player)->next->next->next->next->previous = (*player)->next->next- 
>next;
(*player)->next->next->next->next->next = NULL;
(*computer)->next->previous = *computer;
(*computer)->next->next->previous = (*computer)->next;
(*computer)->next->next->next->previous = (*computer)->next->next;
(*computer)->next->next->next->next->previous = (*computer)->next- 
>next->next;
(*computer)->next->next->next->next->next = NULL;
}
void valueprint(int x) {
printf("Royal Flush          10♠ J♠ Q♠ K♠ A♠\n\n");
printf("Straight Flush       2♣ 3♣ 4♣ 5♣ 6♣\n\n"); 
printf("Four of a Kind       9♣ 9♠ 9♥ 9♦ ■\n\n");
printf("Full House           9♣ 9♠ 9♥ 3♥ 3♠\n\n");
printf("Flush                ■♥ ■♥ ■♥ ■♥ ■♥\n\n");
printf("Straight             4■ 5■ 6■ 7■ 8■\n\n");
printf("Three of a Kind      9♣ 9♠ 9♥ ■ ■\n\n");
printf("Two Pair             K♠ K♣ 6♠ 6♥ ■\n\n");
printf("Jacks or Better      J♣ J♠ ■ ■ ■\n\n");
}
void computerhand(card *currentnode) {
printf("\n\n\n");

}
int main(void) {
int x = 1;
valueprint(x);
srand((int)time(NULL));
card *headl = NULL;
createdeck(&headl);
printdeck(headl);
shuffle(headl);
printdeck(headl);
card* player = NULL;
card* computer = NULL;
drawhand(&player, &computer, &headl);
printf("Computer/Dealer's hand:\n");
computerhand(computer);
printf("Your hand:\n");
printdeck(player);
```

Comment: `'♠'` this is a UTF-8 character. `currentNode->suit` is a `char`. Listen to your compiler warnings. Move to `wchar` and `wprintf`.

Comment: @KamilCuk What do you mean by "UTF-8 character"?

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't know; what do you mean by "UTF-8 character"? Without context that term makes as much sense to me as an "mp3 character" or a "CSV character".

Comment: @melpomene A UTF-8 character has a variable size, while a `char` is only 8 bits. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8